# Why isn't midrash rabbah learnt as much as other commentaries

Tags: torah-study, midrash, commentaries

I feel like there's more of a stress to learn other commentaries, and midrash rabbah and tanchuma are just nice things extra if you want to. I see amazing droshos in the midrash, and was wondering why it's not seized as a pearl.

Comment: Rashi's commentary on the Chumash draws extensively from the midrashim.

Comment: Midrash can easily be seriously misunderstood if learned the wrong way.

Comment: From what I know about the history of Rashi's commentary, before Rashi - most people learned straight from midrashim to understand Tanach. However, midrashim, while nice, are often very long and contain many, many ideas on each verse, sometime contradictory or seemingly so.

Comment: Also, as the centuries passed, less and less people could properly understand the language. Came Rashi with a solution: Condensing the midrashim by choosing the most key ideas + occasional French or German translations for some of the tougher words. And from their the ball started rolling and Rashi's commentary became very popular. He wasn't the first commentator, but I think he was the first to do an expansive yet simple version for Anglo-Franco-Germanic Jews and from there it spread across Europe.

Comment: It depends where you look. Yalkut Meam Loez was for centuries the most widely printed and studied commentary on the Torah and is probably 60% made up of midrash rabbah

Comment: I feel like there’s more of a stress to learn Midrash Rabbah.

Comment: Most people focus on pshat commentaries.